# Error: raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr)) AttributeError: <unknown>.Slides

Tags: python, pywin32

Hi I am trying to run a script that takes the first slide from a template ppt and adds it to an existing ppt. It then takes the 2nd slide from the template and adds it to the end of the ppt. It seems to work on single files but when i put it in a loop, it works for the first file but throws an error for the second. Any ideas?

```
import win32com.client
import os

for i in range(0,len(pptx)):
    ppt_instance = win32com.client.Dispatch('PowerPoint.Application')
    read_only = True
    has_title = False
    window = False
    prs = ppt_instance.Presentations.open(template_path, read_only, has_title, 
    window)
    prs1 = ppt_instance.Presentations.open(ppt+pptx[i], read_only, has_title, 
    window)
    prs.Slides(1).Copy()
    prs1.Slides.Paste(Index=1)
    prs.Slides(2).Copy()
    prs1.Slides.Paste(Index=-1)
    prs1.SaveAs(save_location+pptx[i]+'.pptx')
    prs1.Close()
    prs.Close()

    ppt_instance.Quit()
    del ppt_instance
```

> **Error -:** raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self.*username*, attr)) AttributeError: .Slides

Comment: first you have  big problem of indentation

Comment: There is no start of for loop an In which line your for loop ends

Comment: oh i realised i didnt indent properly in the question. In my code, the loop executes for 2 files before throwing an error